# #pragma mark text field delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

what is this #pragma mark text field delegates?

It is like a comment? or what is this used for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"#pragma mark" labels will show up in the function list drop-down in Xcode, so you can use it to add separators or labels to groups of functions.

Comment: How do you bring up the drop down?